# Auto save files downloaded from web page to specific path

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA which takes input as URL and with the URL searches for the Download button or label and clicks it to generate a output. I am able to reach to this level however I want to intervene in between and allow the file to save to a specified path rather than IE prompting me to save. I want to avoid this manual intervention hence reaching out.

I found code for downloading web content but it was downloading page details instead of saving the file on an event.

The following is the code that am using:

```
   ' Create InternetExplorer Object
   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
   ie.Visible = False

   ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
   ie.Navigate "web page"

   For Each oHTML_Element In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
       MsgBox oHTML_Element.innerHTML
       If oHTML_Element.innerHTML = "Download portfolio" Then
           oHTML_Element.Click
       End If
   Next
```

How can I ensure that the file is saved directly to path I provide instead of waiting for me to save manually.

Comment: not sure I understand... why not remove the msgbox & the if // end if?

Comment: The download button action on the webpage is handled by the browser/web server.  The save dialog that opens is default behavior by your browser.  I can't think of a way to intercept this with VBA but my guess is that you wont be able to due to security measures in place by the browser.

Comment: What kind of element is it that you are clicking on, is it a hyperlink, a button?

Comment: I am able to crack till clicking the save option however I want to get to a point where the file gets stored with the path and filename user inputs, currently its saving at the default path. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Pasting the code here....